# Remove Thumbnail Inside Posts - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to hide the blog post thumbnails inside the blogposts, but at the same time I want to keep the thumbnails in my blog overview.

So far, I used the following CSS to make the thumbnail images disappear:

```
.attachment-post-thumbnail {display:none;}
```

However, this also makes them disappear on my blog overview: www.wavebutler.surf/surf-blog

Could anybody help me and let me know what CSS I could use to make the thumbnails disappear inside the posts. It would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Has your blog overview or the blogposts got another container element or element with a different class? If not you need to somehow set another class on one of those containers so you can distinguish

Comment: Many shared classes for both pages (hard to find right selector)... if css solution exists, it will not be elegant (maybe). In this case, you can rather modify template for post page, and remove image/thumbnail from it. Shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll go for the modification of the post page template then! You are probably right about the CSS solution not being smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found your solution or not but, Depending on your themes structure, in single.php look for something like

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) :

    the_post_thumbnail();

endif;
```

If you remove it from single.php or comment it out your single posts will no longer have your featured images

This could also be located in content.php which in this case you can just put a conditional statement on it.

```
if(!is_single()) :
    if(has_post_thumbnail()) :

        the_post_thumbnail();

    endif;
else :
    // continue on 
endif;
```

Probably won't be this general as again it will depend on your theme but in a nut shell is how it can be done.